# Cant install Selinux policy

Tags: linux, dpkg, selinux, error-handling

I am trying to install `selinux` on my librem14 pureos machine, every time I run `sudo apt-get install selinux-policy-default`
I get:

```
dpkg: error processing package selinux-policy-default (--configure):
 installed selinux-policy-default package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 selinux-policy-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```